# How to put text in figure using matplotlib in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to plot multiple figures in a loop using `matplotlib` in `python3`. For every element in loop I draw the actual curve and Fitted curve. Here is the code that I have written:

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(t, y,'g--',label="data")

plt.ylabel("Rate")
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.title("{},{},{}".format(a,b,c),fontsize=8)

plt.text(0.8,0.8,"R-sq:"+str(round(r_squared,2)),fontsize=8)
plt.text(0.8,0.7,"decay:"+str(round(1/(12*fit_b),2)),fontsize=8)

plt.text(40.1,1.0,"#Cohort:"+str(C),fontsize=8)
plt.text(40.1,0.9,"Samples:"+str(int(S)),fontsize=8)

plt.grid()

plt.plot(t, yhat, 'b--',label='Fitted Function:\n $y = %0.4f e^{%0.4f t} $' % (fit_a, fit_b))
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.4, 0.4), fancybox=True, shadow=True) #1.4, 1.1

name="./fig_weight/{}__{}__{}.png".format(a,b,c)
plt.savefig(name)
plt.show()
```

I am trying to put `R-squared, Decay value and several other things` in figure so that it is easy to visualize. For some of the plots alignment is fine but for others the text goes outside plot area. 
I am running the same code for different iteration.
How to fix it?

Here are the plots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Take a look at matplotlib annotate documentation: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `plt.text` location values with fixed numbers but your axis range is changing. One option is to plot locations based on your data, for example the last `[-1]` or middle `[int(t.shape[0]/2.)]` element on your curve with a shift `tshift` to offset the text, e.g.

```
plt.text(t[-1]+tshift, y[-1]+tshift,"R-sq:"+str(round(r_squared,2)),fontsize=8)
```